# How to fade in text while fading out an image?

Tags: html, css

I have text on top of an image that I'd like to fade in when the image is hovered over, while the image fades out. I've managed to get the transitions to work on the text and the image, but when I hover over the text, the image goes back to full opacity. I'm trying to make it so that when the text is hovered over, the image stays faded out. Here's my code:

```css
.container img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .6s ease;
}

.container img:hover {
  opacity: .4;
}

.gallery-image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .6s ease;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.gallery-image:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you switch the order and have the `div` before the `img`, this should achieve what you are looking for:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gallery-image">
        <div class="text">text</div>
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the hover state on the the parent container `.gallery-image`.

```
.gallery-image:hover img {
  opacity: .4;
}

.gallery-image:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
.container img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .6s ease;
}

.gallery-image:hover img {
  opacity: .4;
}

.gallery-image:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .6s ease;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery-image">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```